# Finding a non existing value in a column PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dspace

I'm working on a DSpace 5.10 repository with PostgrSQL 9.x. The problem is that when harvested, there are a lot of items that lack metadata required by the regulating entity of my country. Is there a way to bring up which itemID's don't have a specific field?

For example:

I need a query that gives me as result all the resource_id that don't have a metadatafield_id = X. A same resource_id has many metadata_field_id entries.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please review [ask] Using that as a template for your question greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In particular post your table DDL, sample test data as [formatted text](https://www.worldometers.info/) - **no images**, and the expected results from that data. Show what you have tried and be specific about what issue you have.

Comment: Unrelated, but: "9.x" covers **7 major versions** many of them [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Although probably not important for this question, you should tell us your exact version nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you properly:

1. You're looking to return all `resource_id` that don't have `X` in the field `metadatafield_id`.
2. There are multiple rows per `resource_id`, but only some of those rows don't contain `X` in their respective `metadata_field_id` columns.

If so, try this:

```
SELECT distinct resource_id
FROM your_table_name
WHERE metadata_field_id != 'X'
```

By using `distinct`, you remove all duplicate rows. In this way, you'll only return unique `resource_id`. Without using `distinct`, you will return duplicate entries for `resource_id` in your result.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is the PostgreSQL documentation for `distinct`.

*EDIT:* `distinct` is only supported on PostgreSQL versions 9.5+

Comment: `distinct` has been supported by all Postgres versions since [at least 7.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/sql-select.html#R1-SQL-SELECT-1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the list of all items that doesn't have a specific metadata, so the easier way is to exclude from the complete list the ones that actually have such metadata

```
select item_id from item where item_id not in 
(
   select resource_id from resourcepolicy where 
      resource_type_id = 2 and metadata_field_id = ?
);
```